# (Alt +-) typing = instead of <- in RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio

Until recently I was using (Alt +-) normally as a shortcut to <- , but for some reason it only works when typing a script. If I am using RMarkdown, it will insert = instead of <-

I may have pressed something wrong by accident, but I can't change it and it's really annoying because I am already used to <-

Does anyone know how to change it back to normal?

Comment: Go to Tools, Modify keyboard shortcuts, and filter to "Insert assignment operator".

Comment: In this option I can change the shortcut. For normal scripts, the shortcut return "<-" normally, but it still returns "=" instead of "<-" in RMarkdown.

Comment: That's curious - maybe file a bug report? https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues In the meantime, what if you reinstall RStudio? Or even just hit "Reset..."?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I was in an Rmd text portion, the shortcut does output = as the assignment operator, but if you are in a coding chunk the shortcut should output a <- as the assignment operator.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide some code to show exactly what you mean.